# Android Twitter kit home timeline optional parameter issue

Tags: android, twitter, twitter-rest-api, twitterkit

I am consuming few apis from [TwitterKit](https://dev.twitter.com/twitterkit/android/overview). I want to fetch home timeline of user where user will see list of tweets from his follower. If we check the api documentation for [home timeline](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/statuses/home_timeline), the parameters are optional. Now twitter kit provides all required things. I found the way to access the home timeline api through Twitter kit only, but problem is its returning 400 always. If you noticed even if the parameter is optional I have to pass them. Find the code below.

Actual method in the Twitter Kit

```
/**
     * Returns a collection of the most recent Tweets and retweets posted by the authenticating user
     * and the users they follow. The home timeline is central to how most users interact with the
     * Twitter service.
     * <p>
     * The Twitter REST API goes back up to 800 tweets on the home timeline.
     * It is more volatile for users that follow many users or follow users who Tweet frequently.
     *
     * @param count (optional) Specifies the number of tweets to try and retrieve, up to a maximum
     *              of 200. The value of count is best thought of as a limit to the number of tweets
     *              to return because suspended or deleted content is removed after the count has
     *              been applied. We include retweets in the count, even if include_rts is not
     *              supplied. It is recommended you always send include_rts=1 when using this API
     *              method.
     * @param sinceId (optional) Returns results with an ID greater than (that is, more recent than)
     *                the specified ID. There are limits to the number of Tweets which can be
     *                accessed through the API. If the limit of Tweets has occurred since the
     *                since_id, the since_id will be forced to the oldest ID available.
     * @param maxId (optional) Returns results with an ID less than (that is, older than) or equal
     *              to the specified ID.
     * @param trimUser (optional) When set to either true, t or 1, each Tweet returned in a timeline
     *                 will include a user object including only the status authors numerical ID.
     *                 Omit this parameter to receive the complete user object.
     * @param excludeReplies (optional) This parameter will prevent replies from appearing in the
     *                       returned timeline. Using exclude_replies with the count parameter will
     *                       mean you will receive up-to count tweets — this is because the count
     *                       parameter retrieves that many tweets before filtering out retweets and
     *                       replies. This parameter is only supported for JSON and XML responses.
     * @param contributeDetails (optional) This parameter enhances the contributors element of the
     *                          status response to include the screen_name of the contributor. By
     *                          default only the user_id of the contributor is included.
     * @param includeEntities (optional) The entities node will be disincluded when set to false.
     */
    @GET("/1.1/statuses/home_timeline.json?" +
            "tweet_mode=extended&include_cards=true&cards_platform=TwitterKit-13")
    Call<List<Tweet>> homeTimeline(@Query("count") Integer count,
                                   @Query("since_id") Long sinceId,
                                   @Query("max_id") Long maxId,
                                   @Query("trim_user") Boolean trimUser,
                                   @Query("exclude_replies") Boolean excludeReplies,
                                   @Query("contributor_details") Boolean contributeDetails,
                                   @Query("include_entities") Boolean includeEntities);
```

The way I have to call this is

```
val homeTimeline = TwitterCore.getInstance().apiClient.statusesService.homeTimeline(100, 344796632681967616, Long.MAX_VALUE, true, false, false, false)
        homeTimeline.enqueue(object : Callback<List<Tweet>>() {
            override fun success(result: Result<List<Tweet>>) {
                toast(result.data?.size.toString())
            }

            override fun failure(exception: TwitterException) {
                toast(exception.message.toString())
            }
        })
```

Can anyone guide me if I am missing anything? Consumer and secret Keys are configured correctly as I can receive user timeline already.